PopScope with arguments
I am trying to navigate back to a previous screen from my current screen.
OnWillPop was deprecated thus I am using PopScope with the following code
  canPop: true,
  onPopInvoked: (didPop)
  {
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>
    StepperScreen(param1: widget.param1, param2: widget.param2)),(Route<dynamic>route)=>false);
  },
  child: Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(.... 

On the back button for the IOS it works perfectly but not on the PopScope
    StepperScreen(param1: widget.param1, param2: widget.param2)),(Route<dynamic>route)=>false);

Is there something I'm missing, or should I use a different routing call?
I get the following response from the editor
I/ViewRootImpl@1beec50[MainActivity](28298): ViewPostIme key 1
D/Activity(28298): onKeyDown(KEYCODE_BACK)
D/Activity(28298): onKeyUp(KEYCODE_BACK) isTracking()=true isCanceled()=false hasCallback=false 

Then the entire apps back navigation is broken and not even the back button in the app bar wants to work

The navigation is causing problem because you have set canPop as true. So on click of back btn when navigation goes to previous screen. The onPopInvoked function is called. Which all try to invoke navigator. And invoking navigator while navigation is already in process will throw error. So what you should do is set canPop as false. So whenever user tries to go back via back btn. It will not pop and invoke the onPopInvoked fn and it will work

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
     canPop: false,
     onPopInvoked : (didPop){
     Navigator.pop(context);  // return Future<bool>.value(true); 
     },
     child: Scaffold()
   );
}

In a class its provide the back gestures in the case of a form with unsaved data. The didPop parameter indicates whether or not the back navigation actually happened successfully.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Here is an example of how to implement PopScope:
return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) {
        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }

        _showDialog();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: ArchiveTvAppBar(

With this example we open a dialog before poping, but you can do whatever else you want.
Naturally in this example, in he _showDialog method, a pop is done for really poping when the user validate the dialog.
